# How to exclude paths when using GroupedOpenAPI with SpringDoc

Tags: springdoc

I have recently swopped out SpringFox for SpringDoc.

Previously I was able to exclude paths to be used for the Swagger UI like so:

```
new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).paths(Predicates.not(PathSelectors.regex("/path1/.*|/path2/.*|/path4/.*")))
```

In the case above, the Swagger UI would display for path3 and path5.

Making use of the GroupedOpenAPI when using SpringDoc, I have only seen a way to explicitly set which paths should be allowed e.g.

```
GroupedOpenApi.builder()
            .pathsToMatch("/path3/**", "/path5/**")
```

I would prefer to have a more generic way, whereby I can specify which paths NOT to allow, so if I add further paths they will be allowed by default. Something like:

```
GroupedOpenApi.builder()
            .pathsToMatch("!/path1/**", "!/path2/**", "!/path4/**")
```

Not sure if there is any functionality like this supported. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the follwoing property, to exclude paths (Tested with v1.2.32)

```
springdoc.paths-to-exclude= /test
```

Or:

```
GroupedOpenApi.builder()
            .pathsToExclude("!/path1/**", "!/path2/**", "!/path4/**")
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you. I see this functionality was added 18 days ago - only 4 days after I posted the above.

Comment: Great Rick. You should accept the answer i guess then :)

Comment: Will this `springdoc.paths-to-exclude= /test` go inside application.properties. It shows `Cannot resolve configuration property 'springdoc.paths-to-exclude' `